# multiprocessing not using all cores while running simple script in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, performance, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I am a trying to understand why not all the cores are being used, I have an I7 with 6 cores and 12 logical processors.

I am trying to calculate a diversity index on a large dataframe(1,2mln rows and a subsets of the dataframe which is 1/3 of the rows).

So far I have tried to only run it on the subset. I think that the process is simply stuck, since I have been running this script for ~10hrs

here is the code I have been using

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from support_functions import functions
from multiprocessing import Pool
p= Pool(12)

DF = pd.read_csv("H:/data_micro/Feces2tpsF.csv")

#calculate the shannon diversity

def calcIndex(DATAF, levelDF):
    DATAF["Pi"] = DATAF["log2Smooth"].groupby(level=["PatientID", "Timepoint"]).apply(lambda x:  x / x.sum())
    DATAF["pi*lnpi"]= DATAF["Pi"]*np.log(DATAF["Pi"])
    DATAF["H_log2"] = DATAF["pi*lnpi"].groupby(level=["PatientID", "Timepoint"]).apply(
    lambda x:  x.sum()*-1)
    return DATAF

DF_Feces_FAVF = DF[(DF["Phylum"]== "vic")]
DF_Feces_FAVF = DF_Feces_FAVF.set_index(["PatientID", "Timepoint", "Phylum"])

DF_Feces_FAVF = p.map(calcIndex,DF_Feces_FAVF )
p.start()
p.close()
p.join()
```

my dataframe looks as follows:

| Sample nr | smooth | Phylum | timepoint | PatientID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA35456 | 24.7361 | fam | 1 | 121 |
| AA35456 | 107.3580 | fam | 1 | 121 |
| AA35456 | 72.0639 | fam | 1 | 121 |
| AA35456 | 43.8766 | vic | 1 | 121 |
| AA35456 | 2382.8700 | vic | 1 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 49.6488 | vic | 1 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 3 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 43.8766 | vic | 3 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 3 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 43.8766 | vic | 3 | 121 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 3 | 123 |
| AA35442 | 43.8766 | vic | 3 | 123 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 6 | 126 |
| AA35442 | 43.8766 | vic | 6 | 126 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 6 | 126 |
| AA35442 | 43.8766 | vic | 6 | 126 |
| AA35444 | 72.0639 | fam | 6 | 126 |
| AA35442 | 43.8766 | vic | 6 | 126 |

and this is my cpu usage currently[image: cpu usage]

Also I am running this in jupyter notebook.
I'd appreciate any help on this, thx!

Comment: After some more testing I am getting the following error in my debug console: AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'calcIndex' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>

Comment: So, this is going to create 1.2 million processes, and each process is going to need a copy of your 1.2 million row DataFrame.  Yes, that's going to take a LOT of time, and most of it is unproductive time.  This might not be the best way to handle this data.  Have you tried multithreading, so they can share the same memory space?

Comment: @TimRoberts that's only going to create 12 processes, as indicated when the pool is created.  `map` is also somewhat [sensible with batch sizes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f0d266af952ac140ea9ab68e65f4a423acd0672/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L481) so this won't even translate into a million context switches

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Pools before, but the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) function takes an iterable so I would expect it to pass jobs to the pool one by one. If this is the case, the workers will be spending most of their time marshalling data. I would try setting `chunksize` to something like `len(df) // core_count`. This should minimise any marshalling overhead.

You could do this with something like:

```py
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

def get_chunk_size(task_count: int) -> int:
    return (task_count // cpu_count()) + 1
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and even made a slight adjustment def get_chunk_size(task_count: int) -> int:
    return (len(task_count) // (cpu_count()*4)) + 1 making the chunks even smaller and  I used a subset of the original df which has   462396 rows. This resulted in 
chunksizes of : 9634 row  but so far I have been running the script for 14hours and nothing has happened

Comment: doubt this is the issue, multiprocessing is sensible with chunk sizes, see my comment above for a link into the source to see that it already does something similar to this